# GORM hangs with parameter

Tags: go, go-gorm

The below queries hangs exactly after 5 calls every time,

```
tx := db.Raw("select count(*) as hash from transaction_logs left join blocks on transaction_logs.block_number = blocks.number"+
        " where (transaction_logs.address = ? and transaction_logs.topic0 = ?) and blocks.total_confirmations >= 7 "+
        "group by transaction_hash", strings.ToLower("0xa11265a58d9f5a2991fe8476a9afea07031ac5bf"),
        "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef").Scan(&totalIds)
```

If we replace it without the arguments it works

```
db.Raw("select count(*) as hash from transaction_logs left join blocks on transaction_logs.block_number = blocks.number"+
        " where (transaction_logs.address = @tokenAddress and transaction_logs.topic0 = '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef') and blocks.total_confirmations >= 7 "+
        "group by transaction_hash", sql.Named("tokenAddress", strings.ToLower("0xa11265a58d9f5a2991fe8476a9afea07031ac5bf"))
```

Tried even with named parameter, same result

Can anyone help here

Comment: looks likes a bug description about the mssql driver, maybe ? which driver are you using ? Can you post a reproducible example ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Send a SIGQUIT to get a goroutine dump and see where it's hanging.